# How to write infinite loop in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

How do I write an infinite loop in VHDL? Whats wrong with:

```
while 1 loop
  --sequential statements/code
end loop;
```

Comment: In VHDL, every process is an infinite loop actually. You don't need to write loops like in programming languages since it is an hardware description. Take a look at this http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhklenke/tutorials/vhdl/modules/m12_23/sld008.htm

Comment: `loop ... end loop;` The `while 1`bit  is unnecessary unless you want a terminating condition. It's also a type error, you presumably meant `while true`.Even without it you can 'exit' from the loop. See also Jeff's answer if you're intending this to run in hardware.

Comment: I'm confused why everyone assumes this has to be synthesized. Infinite loops are perfectly fine in rtl test benches. You're then stuck with an rtl test bench, but that's a different problem altogether.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with your example is that when code is synthesized, all loops are unrolled; an infinite loop would then produce infinite logic, and that's not going to fit into any real silicon device.

You'll need to add some context if you are looking for help in achieving something in particular.

Answer (score 2):

In synthesizable VHDL, loops make duplicates of circuitry. There is no notion of an infinite loop because the target device (FPGA) does not have an infinite number of logic gates.

Are you trying to write a computer program in VHDL as if it was a microprocessor? It sounds like it and I'd encourage you to understand the distinction between writing software compared to designing digital circuits in VHDL. Good luck and there's plenty of text about on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like this (someone please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
process (clock)
begin
  -- statements
end process;
```

You do need a `clock` signal to make it work though.

Answer (score 0):

create a **PROCESS (CLK)** block to always restart a sequential circuit with finite **LOOP** inside. Process act as interrupt sensitivity list. just make sure to inject lower CLK period than the whole sequential circuit propagation to prevent **BottleNeck** error. LOOP directive sure taken a length of time.